# Invalid syntax error with numba installed with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, numba

When I try to run this Python code inside my `virtualenv`:

```
#!./env/bin/python3

from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)

print("Hello World")
```

I got the following error:

```
(env) root@LANTI-PC:/mnt/c/www/python/flask/app# ./test.py
  File "./test.py", line 6
    print("Hello World")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is my `requirements.txt`:

```
click==6.6
Flask==0.11.1
funcsigs==1.0.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
llvmlite==0.12.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
numba==0.27.0
numpy==1.11.1
pybars3==0.9.1
PyMeta3==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.11.10
```

`llvm-config` version: `3.7.1`

Also, If I just do `import numba` or `from numba import jit`, the file will be executed, but marginally slower than if I execute with `python3` only, without any numba import.

Comment: I removed, still the same error appears.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't the problem. The problem is the previous line. What's `@jit()` supposed to do? It's a decorator, which cannot be applied to a function call (`print()`).

Comment: I following this documentation: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.27.0/user/jit.html It states: "Using this decorator, you can mark a function for optimization by Numba’s JIT compiler" I want to setup a simple Hello World python app using the LLVM toolchain to benchmark against another frameworks, like Node/Express, Node/Koa, Go/Iris. I'm never programmed in python before, so forgive me .

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what this does. Numba compiles your function code into more efficient code; `print` is already compiled. You can only apply this to *functions you write*, it doesn't magically speed up Python core functions.

Comment: I see, thank you for clearing this out. Out of this question, but if I want to speed up the entire Python with a simple drop-in replacement of the compiler (including `print`), my only bet is `pypy`? `cython` works the same way as `numba`?

Comment: Do you have any indication that `print` is slow?! The built-in core C modules of Python will generally already be pretty darn fast, because they're written in C (in case of CPython) and have already been compiled. Even PyPy states this on their site (http://pypy.org/features.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove your usage of `@jit` decorator, because there are no function to decorate there, they's why the error. Decorators wrap the functions so without them they are useless and erronous.